# react hook not working, I am not able to bring the values in the front end - map is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using react using axios in react

```
  const [testresults, setTestreults] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {​​​​​​​
    axios.get('https://localhost:5001/api/xyz')
                .then(response =>
                 setTestreults(JSON.stringify(response)));
}​​​​​​​, [testresults]);
```

in the  html the data is not populating

```
                           {​​​​​(testresults && testresults.length > 0) && testresults.map(testresult =>
                                        <tr key={​​​​​testresult.ResultId}​​​​​>
                                            <td>{​​​​​testresult.ResultId}​​​​​</td>
                                            <td>{​​​​​testresult.IN_session_id}​​​​​</td>
                                            <td>{​​​​​testresult.ret_testId}​​​​​</td>
                                            <td>{​​​​​testresult.ret_TestType}​​​​​</td>
                                            <td>{​​​​​testresult.ret_result}​​​​​</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )}​​​​​
```

Comment: You need to make sure testResults is an array. Why are you calling JSON.stringify on the response?

Comment: because you are stringifying the response yourself while updating the state

Comment: will this works-  useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://localhost:5001/api/xyz').then(response => setTestreults(json.data))
    }, []);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.map` function is only available on array.
It looks like **testresults** isn't in the format you are expecting it to be (it is {} but you are expecting []).

1. First, console log the response and get an idea about the structure of the response.
2. Then access the required data array

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {​​​​​​​
    axios.get('https://localhost:5001/api/xyz')
                .then(response =>
                 setTestreults(response.data));
}​​​​​​​, [testresults]);
```

Comment: {ResultId: 1, IN_session_id: "Android", ret_testId: "ABC123", ret_TestType: "Offer1", ret_result: "xyz234"}
IN_session_id: "Android"
ResultId: 1
ret_TestType: "Offer1"
ret_result: "xyz234"
ret_testId: "ABC123"
__proto__: Object                      But UI not showing when i tried                                     <ul>
                                        {
                                        (data && data.length > 0) && data.map(user => <li key={user.ResultId}>{user.ResultId}</li>)
                                        }

                                    </ul>